# Using @csrf_protect on view GET methods

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, django-csrf, django-1.5

Most of my GET requests are fired by Angular which makes it easy to set the CSRF Token in the header. This already works out of the box for POST requests, however I was wondering whether I could use CSRF protection for GET requests as well.

My initial instinct was to add `@csrf_protect` before the View's get method, for instance:

```
class ProjectView(View):
    @csrf_protect
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

However this produces the error:

```
AttributeError at /project
'ProjectView' object has no attribute 'COOKIES'

File "c:\Apps\msysgit\simpletask\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\csrf.py" in process_view
  95.                 request.COOKIES[settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME])
```

So I'm guessing there's something which a POST request provides which a GET request does not. Is there a better way to do this?

Also, before anybody mentions that all sensitive information should be pulled via POST requests (as I've seen a few times lately), my reason for trying to stick with GET is I'm trying to build according to RESTful guidelines, meaning GET requests are for pulling data, POST is for new records, PUT is for updates and DELETE is for data deletion.

**EDIT**:

Since there seems to be a sentiment that I shouldn't be attempting the above, while I do now agree somewhat, the exploit(s) I'm attempting to prevent are discussed in these 3 links:

- http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx
- http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/24/json-hijacking.aspx
- http://balpha.de/2013/02/plain-text-considered-harmful-a-cross-domain-exploit/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you quite understand what CSRF actually protects. CSRF exploits the trust that a site has in a user's browser; by exploiting a session cookie that allows the attacker to run commands on behalf of the user.

The site trusts the request because it hasn't expired the session cookie for the browser. This is why in most CSRF mitigation techniques a unique OTP for each request that has a side effect is generated. The attacker would not know the key generated for the OTP, and hence cannot forge a legitimate request.

For all URLs that have a side effect (like POST, PUT, DELETE) you would need CSRF. For GET it doesn't make any sense to have it, since GET requests - **if you are doing REST correctly** - should be idempotent - if run multiple times, they return the same results and they should not have any side effects.

CSRF protection does not prevent information disclosure or man in the middle attacks. So if you have sensitive information you want to protect, use HTTPS. To prevent unregulated use of your API, use authentication and authorization.

Comment: This. @csrf_protect with GET requests makes no sense. Note however that idempotence isn't the same as side effect free. PUT and DELETE are idempotent, but not side effect free. CSRF is needed for requests that have side effect, not because they're idempotent.

Comment: I guess I was trying to cover the issue described here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx However on further reading it seems like a pretty ancient exploit that modern browsers have taken care of.

Comment: Also this followup, which is not quite as old, and at the time of writing appeared to be more widespread: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/24/json-hijacking.aspx

Comment: Further reading at http://balpha.de/2013/02/plain-text-considered-harmful-a-cross-domain-exploit/ seems to suggest that all GET requests returning JSON should simply return Object and not arrays.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. It is useful to have csrf_protect on a GET for a web app which then makes AJAX posts back to the server. csrf_protect is what will set the csrftoken cookie that needs to be posted back in the AJAX post.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `method_decorator`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-the-class

So your code will be

```
class ProjectView(View):`
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

**[EDIT]**
However `csrf_protect` will check only POST requests (it has `if request.method == 'POST' check) so you have to implement something by your own.